# Is it possible to merge to existing observable without creating a new observable?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

For example I have an Observable property in the base class

```
protected bzMaker: Observable<string>;

this.bzMaker = Observable.fromEvent(input, 'click').map(() => 'click');
this.bzMaker.subscribe(value => console.log(value);
```

Is it possible to merge another observable after `subscribe` without creation a new obsrevable?
like:

```
this.bzMaker.mergeOperation(Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keydown').map(() => 'keydown')
```

I want to keep all the subscription and see 'keydown' string in console on each keydow and 'click' string on each click.

Comment: There are ways, but they are a bit more sophisticated. What is your particular use case here? Are you sure it wont be enough to just `merge(a$, b$).subscribe(...)`?

Comment: I just want to override base class property by merging with new observable, so unfortunately rxjs `merge` is not right for this.

Comment: Unless you can modify the base class — you can't interfere with that subscription chain in RxJS. If you can modify it — then something like `bzMakerSubj$ = new Subject(); bzMakerSubj$.mergeMap(o$ => o$).subscribe(); bzMakerSubj$.next(Observable.fromEvent(...))` would work. I think if we could understand your use case better — we could suggest a cleaner solution.